# Remove/set the non-zero diagonal elements of a sparse matrix in scipy

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, diagonal

Say I would like to remove the diagonal from a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`. Is there an efficient way of doing so? I saw that in the `sparsetools` module there are `C` functions to return the diagonal.

Based on other SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129948/scipy-sparse-set-row-to-zeros) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784868/what-is-most-efficient-way-of-setting-row-to-zeros-for-a-sparse-scipy-matrix) my current approach is the following:

```python
def csr_setdiag_val(csr, value=0):
    """Set all diagonal nonzero elements
    (elements currently in the sparsity pattern)
    to the given value. Useful to set to 0 mostly.
    """
    if csr.format != "csr":
        raise ValueError('Matrix given must be of CSR format.')
    csr.sort_indices()
    pointer = csr.indptr
    indices = csr.indices
    data = csr.data
    for i in range(min(csr.shape)):
        ind = indices[pointer[i]: pointer[i + 1]]
        j =  ind.searchsorted(i)
        # matrix has only elements up until diagonal (in row i)
        if j == len(ind):
            continue
        j += pointer[i]
        # in case matrix has only elements after diagonal (in row i)
        if indices[j] == i:
            data[j] = value
```

which I then follow with

```python
csr.eliminate_zeros()
```

Is that the best I can do without writing my own `Cython` code?

Comment: Is `scr_matrix.setdiag` not sufficient?

Comment: `setdiag` takes an array and also sets elements that were previously not in the matrix. So adding new elements to the matrix is costly but I haven't compared them.

Comment: How about creating a new sparse matrix with the diagonal that you want to remove, and subtract it?  You may need to run a 'compress' function to fully remove entries.

Comment: Great idea! You can [see the results in this IPython Notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/Midnighter/9992103). Cythonizing the function above may give it a slight speed boost but subtraction is easiest for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @hpaulj's comment, I created an IPython Notebook which [can be seen on nbviewer](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/Midnighter/9992103). This shows that out of all methods mentioned the following is the fastest (assume that `mat` is a sparse CSR matrix):

```python
mat - scipy.sparse.dia_matrix((mat.diagonal()[scipy.newaxis, :], [0]), shape=(one_dim, one_dim))
```