# Finding row indices corresponding to a specific value on a diagonal in sparse matrices

Tags: python, python-3.x, sparse-matrix

I had a question related to sparse matrices.
I start with a matrix A:

```
import numpy as np
A =  np.array([[ 2,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1],
       [ 0,  4, -1,  2, -1,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  3, -1,  1, -1],
       [-1,  2, -1,  3, -1, -1],
       [ 0, -1,  1, -1,  2,  0],
       [-1,  0, -1, -1,  0,  1]])
```

then I generate a sparse matrix (this is an example, the matrices I work with have 10k plus entries)

```
import scipy as sparse
M = sparse.csr_matrix(A)
```

Now, from this I will need to extract the diagonal (no problem there)

```
M.diagonal()
Out: array([2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1])
```

And.. here is where I am stuck...

From the diagonal I would like to check all entries with a specific value, let's say 4, and assess all row indices where 4 is found on the diagonal. IN this specific example, this should 
yield something like:
[1]

From those indices I need to assess all row values (excluding the diagonal) of the sparse matrix, and find the maximum value, that, in this case, should be = 2.

Another example, if I look for 2, row indices should be:
[0],[4], and maximum value = 0 (as 0 is the max value in rows 0, and 4 of the sparse matrix).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can access the indices in which the diagonal is equal to some value, say `val`, via

```
indices = M.diagonal()==val
```

Then we can remove the diagonal from `M` via the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660374/remove-set-the-non-zero-diagonal-elements-of-a-sparse-matrix-in-scipy):

```
M -= sparse.dia_matrix((M.diagonal()[scipy.newaxis, :], [0]), shape=M.shape)
```

and finally find the maximum of the rows of the modified `M` selected via `indices`:

```
np.max(M[indices])
```

Comment: thank you so much! works great! (also I do not have enough reputation to display the upvote, sorry about that!)